# association subobject json POST Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using spring boot and with this problem by sending the POST method
when I have an association of another object.

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/save", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody void save(@RequestBody Poultry poultry){ 

    repository.save(poultry);
}
```

Model:

```
public class Poultry {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotEmpty
@Column(length = 100, nullable = false)
private String name;

private String token;

@ManyToOne
private Center center;
```

Url: http://localhost:8080/poultry/save
Method: POST

Json:

```
{"id":null, "name": "123", "token":"1234", "center":{"id":2, "name":"Test"}}
```

Return method: 400 Bad Request

{
timestamp: 1435236955364
status: 400
error: "Bad Request"
exception: "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException"
message: "Could not read JSON: Template must not be null or empty! (through reference chain: br.com.inobram.cdi.web.model.Poultry["center"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Template must not be null or empty! (through reference chain: br.com.inobram.cdi.web.model.Poultry["center"])"
path: "/poultry/save"
}

**if execute method without object "center" return 200 OK**